# Fabric js not working on IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, fabricjs

I have created whiteboard with fabricjs and javascript. It works fine in chrome and firefox but all of fabricjs functions does work in Edge but not working on IE 11 it is completely blank. How can I fix this problem?
My fabric version is 2.2.3.

internet-explorer-11 fabricjs whiteboard

Comment: Try running this [test](http://fabricjs.com/test/unit/)

Comment: how do i run this Please can you tell me that.

Comment: Just open that link in ie11

Comment: then what to do after that

Comment: All cases passed? And just open fabricjs.com homepage if it works, then there is something wrong in your code

Comment: fabric.Parser: parseStyleAttribute with value normalization, fabric.Parser: parseStyleAttribute with short font declaration

Comment: Can you share your code, how are you initializing canvas?

Comment: these cases did not passed

Comment: how you want me to share my code and which part of the code you are talking about

Comment: That unit test was just to show you fabricjs most of functionality works with ie11, there is some issue with your code I guess

Comment: 738.fabric.Canvas: loadFromJSON with custom properties on Canvas with image, This case also not passed under 5 step which is IndexSizeError

Comment: Just share minimal how you initializing canvas and add only one object with it.